# Setting initial configurations of user session for Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, x11, startup, keyboard-layout

I have to configure the keyboard every session with the command:

```
setxkbmap -layout br
```

And to connect:

```
systemctl start dhcpcd
```

I want the system do this automatic, I've tryed change the .bash_profile and the rc.conf but don't worked.

Comment: There is no `/etc/rc.conf` in Arch, and hasn't been for over two years. Read the wiki entry on keyboard configuration and networking.

Answer (score 1):

The Arch Linux wiki has [a detailled article about configuring the keyboard](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg).

If you want to set it only for your user (after login), you can put the `setxkbmap` command in your `~/.xprofile` or `~/.xinitrc`.

As explained in the wiki, if you want the setting to be global you can create a Xorg configuration file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-keyboard.conf` :

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "yes"
        Option "XkbLayout" "br"
EndSection
```

*Or* use `localectl set-x11-keymap br` to create that configuration file, (and also set the console keyboard layout).

`rc.conf` have been deprecated for quite some time. You shouldn't have one.

`systemctl start service` just start the service. To set it to start at each boot the command is `systemctl enable service`.
The [systemd article in the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) has more details.